# Trying to find certain files using python and regex

Tags: python, string, file-search

So I am currently writing a code in python to find certain files, a key part in my current project. I am using the os and re module (for now) in python. When I do it, I get two results. My current code:

```
import os
import re

counter = 0
inp = input("What are you looking for?:> ")
thisdir = os.getcwd()
for r, d, f in os.walk("C:\\"):
    for file in f:
        filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
        filepathCheck = filepath
        if str(filepathCheck) is not re.search(r"((.+?).lnk)", str(filepath)):
            if inp in filepathCheck:
                counter += 1
                print(filepathCheck)

print("There are", counter, "files.")
```

The results I am getting are:

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\Secrets.txt.lnk
C:\Users\test\Documents\Secrets.txt
There are 2 files.
```

I do not want to print out the file ending in .lnk and I just want the file in Documents. If anyone is able to help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please could you edit your question to describe in words what the aim of the code snippet is?  For example, if it is meant to search somewhere for files of a certain type, while ignoring certain files, or whatever.  It is hard to intuit from code what it is logically meant to do, especially if the code doesn't actually do what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is wrong. I'm not sure what you think the `is not` in `str(filepathCheck) is not re.search(...)` does.

You don't need to use regex to see if a file path ends with `.lnk`! Just do `str.endswith()`<sup>[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)</sup> instead.

Change these lines:

```
if str(filepathCheck) is not re.search(r"((.+?).lnk)", str(filepath)):
    if inp in filepathCheck:
```

to

```
if not filepath.endswith(".lnk") and inp in filepath
```

`filepath` is already a string, so you don't need to convert it to a string again. Also, `filepathCheck` is the same as `filepath`, so just use the same variable